# pgfplots: How to draw a tangent graph below two others?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot, graphs, polynomials

Assumed I want to draw three simple graphs based on the following illustration:

[image: Screenshot of the desired state]

---

How can I plot those three graphs? I've tried to create something like this:

**Minimum Working Example (MWE):**

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
       \begin{axis}[domain=0:1]
         \addplot+[no marks, samples=100] {exp(3*x)};
         \addplot+[no marks, samples=100] {(-exp(3*x)+20)};
       \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

**Screenshot of the current state:**

[image: Screenshot of the current state]

---

**Description of the issue:**

However, I don't get the point on how to figure out the function of the third graph as well as how to clip the graphs in `x` and `y` direction to align them centered in the plot. It is not necessary to be completely precise, the accuracy of my upper template will be fine enough.

How to do that?

Comment: @close-voter: Please explain in a comment your reason for voting to close!

Comment: I accept the Kurt's comment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the function f1*f2/(f1+f2) to get something like what you describe. To make the code a bit clearer I defined the functions `f1` and `f2`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{%
  compat=1.12,
  /pgf/declare function={f1(\x)=exp(3*\x);},
  /pgf/declare function={f2(\x)=-exp(3*\x)+20;},
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
       \begin{axis}[domain=0:1]
         \addplot+[no marks, samples=100] {f1(x)};
         \addplot+[no marks, samples=100] {f2(x)};
         \addplot+[no marks, samples=100] {f1(x)*f2(x)/(f1(x)+f2(x))};
       \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want the function to follow more closely you can use sqrt(f1^2*f2^2/(f1^2+f2^2). Then replace the third plot with

```
\addplot+[no marks, samples=100] {sqrt(f1(x)*f1(x)*f2(x)*f2(x)/(f1(x)*f1(x)+f2(x)*f2(x)))};
```

to get

[image]

Slightly more general, one can use the exponent `\a` (does not have to be an integer):

```
 \foreach \a in {1,...,5}{
   \addplot+[no marks, samples=100] {(f1(x)^\a*f2(x)^\a/(f1(x)^\a+f2(x)^\a))^(1/\a)};
 }
```

[image]

Comment: The lower one looks perfect, thank you very much!!

Comment: Your last edit is simply perfect! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

Are you looking for the minimum? (I shifted the plot a bit but you can of course undo the shift.)

```
\documentclass[border=3.14mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
       \begin{axis}[domain=0:1]
         \addplot+[no marks, samples=100] {exp(3*x)};
         \addplot+[no marks, samples=100] {(-exp(3*x)+20)};
         \addplot+[no marks, samples=6,smooth]
         {min(exp(3*x),(-exp(3*x)+20))-pi/2};
       \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much marmot! The user StefanH has also posted a great approach which looks very smooth - I hope you are not disappointed if I choose his option as an answer?